# get last array from generated data in javascript

Tags: javascript

This data is generated from multiple functions for crossword puzzle.

The problem is that I can't iterate it to get last array which displayed in the grid, even foreach and map is not working:
[image: image from console its groups of generated arrays after every 100ms]

This is the last function relative to this log:

```
let addWord = function( word )
{
    
    wordsF.push(word.text);
    console.log(wordsF);
    for (let letterIndex = 0; letterIndex < word.text.length; ++letterIndex)
    {
        let row = word.row;
        let column = word.column;
        
        if ( word.vertical )
        {
            row += letterIndex; 
        }
        else
        {
            column += letterIndex;
        }
        grid[row][column] = word.text.substring( letterIndex, letterIndex + 1 );
    }
            
}
```

Comment: add some demo of sandbox if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wanna get the last situation wordsF array??
If you do this function can't do that for you. because it has no idea that when last word came.

What you need to do is before sending the word to this function find out if the word is the last word
and if it was last word send a boolean as second argument to function or set a global variable to true.
Then check inside the function if the word is last word then return array.

```
let addWord = function( word, isLastWorld )
{

    wordsF.push(word.text);
    console.log(wordsF);
    for (let letterIndex = 0; letterIndex < word.text.length; ++letterIndex )
    {
        let row = word.row;
        let column = word.column;
        
        if ( word.vertical )
        {
            row += letterIndex; 
        }
        else
        {
            column += letterIndex;
        }
        grid[row][column] = word.text.substring( letterIndex, letterIndex + 1 );
    }

    if( isLastWord ) {
        return wordsF;
    }

}
```

I have no idea about rest of you code. So I'm just gonna simulate it

```
var words = [{
    text: 'word1',
    row: 1,
    column: 1,
    vertical: true
},
{
    text: 'word2',
    row: 1,
    column: 6,
    vertical: true
},
{
    text: 'word3',
    row: 4,
    column: 8,
    horizontal: true
},
{
    text: 'word4',
    row: 2,
    column: 7,
    vertical: true
}];

var lastArray;

for( let i = 0; i < words.length; i++ ) {
    
    if( i == words.length - 1 ) {
        let isLast = true;
        lastArray = addWord( words[i], isLast ):
    }
    else {
        addWord( words[i] );
    }
}
```